# Polarization of light using QM principles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, polarization, superposition

If we have vertical linearly polarized light and if we put it through a polarizing filter oriented at 45 to the vertical, then only half of the light passes through.

I am able to intuitively grasp this fact as photons of vertically polarized light may exist in a superposition of being in two diagonally polarized and mutually perpendicular states, for which the amplitudes interfere. Thus upon interacting with the filter half of the photons pass through.

But if we subsequently pass this light through another filter which is oriented horizontally, still half of this light will pass through.

Why does this happen? Doesn't the fact that it passed through the first filter mean that it is oriented diagonally without uncertainty? How can it, after passing through the first filter, still exist in superposition of two states? Wouldn't the act of passing it through a filter disturb this superposition and force it to occupy one definite state?

Comment: Another way to think of this is to see the polarized light as truly polarized, no super position of states but that the polarizer acts on a probability basis when at 45 degrees.  So a nicely polarized photon arrives at the filter and can't happen to find a nice electron waiting for it in the perfect state or position to cause transmission, so it gets reflected. This happens about 50% of the time for the 45 degree polarizer.

Comment: Just as the vertically polarized photon can be thought as a 'superposition of being in two diagonally polarized and mutually perpendicular states', the diagonally polarized photon can be thought as a 'superposition of a horizontally and a vertically polarized photon'. The type of superposition that you have is defined by the type of measurement you choose to make. Your first measurement projects the polarization of the photon into an eigenstate of the diagonal basis, and the second measurement projects the diagonal polarization into the horizontal/vertical basis.